# ImageMagick - annotation in a for loop with regex?

Tags: regex, for-loop, imagemagick

I can't get regex to work with imagemagick inside a for loop with a regex as annotation.

This is just an example of how I would like to write:

```
$ for i in *.jpg; do convert "$i" -fill white -undercolor '#00000060' -gravity South -pointsize 30 -annotate +0+50 "${i:(\.{2}(.*)\.\w*$'\)}" "./caption/${i%.jpg}-title.jpg" ; done;
```

The part that is wrong is:

```
"${i:(\.{2}(.*)\.\w*$'\)}"
```

Note: The regex does what I like it to do. Removes 2 characters from the start and the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Why regex at all. If your only attempting to remove the first and last 2 characters, it might be easier to substring

```bash
for i in *.jpg
do
    convert "$i" \
        -fill white \
        -undercolor '#00000060' \
        -gravity South \
        -pointsize 30 \
        -annotate +0+50 "${i:1:${#i}-3}" \
        "./caption/${i%.jpg}-title.jpg"
done
```

**Edit from comments**

If you absolutely set on RegEx, I would recommend using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), or another utility that offers extended RegEx support.

```bash
for i in *.jpg
do
    TEXT=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/^..\(.*\)..$/\1/')
    convert "$i" \
        -fill white \
        -undercolor '#00000060' \
        -gravity South \
        -pointsize 30 \
        -annotate +0+50 "$TEXT" \
        "./caption/${i%.jpg}-title.jpg"
done
```

Comment: I am quite new to string manipulation in bash. It's still confusing to me. But I am very familiar with RegEx, you removed your regex solution. It would be great with a working regex solution as it's very flexible for future needs. "${i:1:${#i}-3}" works but why doesn't "${i:1:-3}" nor "${i:1:(-3)}" work??

Comment: And as you know regex can handle strings of different lengths very well and also irregular strings.

Comment: Answer updated to include regex. I original removed regex as I felt it was against [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Thanks again @emcconville!! The sed version works with regex. But sed has some strange implementation of regex. Different syntax with posix and what not. I was a bit unclear in my original description. I ment 2 chars from the start and the whole suffix (of any length) including separator. Now it looks like:    TEXT=$(echo $i | sed -e 's/^.\{2\}\(.*\)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/\1/')